# Can we read a particular page from a pdf file instead of the whole document using PL/SQL?

Tags: pdf, plsql

I am able to read the whole PDF document using `DBMS_LOB.READ()`,but I just want to read the PDF document page by page, is it possible?

And I want this to be done using PL/SQL **only**.

Comment: Is it possible? Technically Yes, but you'll probably need to write the PDF parsing code yourself, because I'm not aware of anyone who has written a parser capable of rendering the visual content of the PDF in a way that would allow you to extract individual "pages" out of it. So - is it practical? No.

Comment: If you can find someone who has written a PDF splitter (one that takes a multi-page PDF and splits it into individual pages), you might be able to port their solution to PL/SQL.

Comment: Here's one to get you started: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/ - but remember I never said this would be easy.